# How to assign a class to a page with a custom template?

Tags: templates, body-class

I tried with the bellow code to assign a body class to a page with a custom template, but this didn't work. What is wrong here?

```
function prefix_conditional_body_class($classes) {
    if ( get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID()) === 'mytemplate.php' ) {
        $classes[] = 'mytemplate';
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'prefix_conditional_body_class' );
```

UPDATE 2

The template is assigned to the page with this code:

```
function my_template_redirect() {
    if ( is_page('search-results') ) : // the page real name
        include (STYLESHEETPATH . '/search-results.php'); // the template real name
        exit;
    endif;
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect' );
```

UPDATE 1

I modified a little the above function and now it works (replaced `get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID()) === "mytemplate.php"` with `is_page( 8 )`, where 8 is the ID of the page):

```
function prefix_conditional_body_class($classes) {
    if ( is_page( 8 ) ) { // the ID of the needed page
        $classes[] = 'mytemplate';
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'prefix_conditional_body_class' );
```

Comment: what is the result of `get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID())` ?

Comment: I added a row to the function: `echo get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID());`, but I don't see an output.

Comment: Add `?><pre><?php var_dump($classes); ?></pre><?php` just before `return $classes;` then check your output from the filter :-)

Comment: this function works only with pages and when you have a page, the template name is already in the classes list of body

Comment: Not in my case. @PieterGoosen, this is the output:  `array(6) { [0]=> string(4) "page" [1]=> string(9) "page-id-8" [2]=> string(21) "page-template-default" [3]=> string(9) "logged-in" [4]=> string(9) "admin-bar" [5]=> string(20) "no-customize-support" } class="page page-id-8 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support">`.

Comment: Where's your `mytemplate.php` located in the theme folder? Is that on the root, or in a subfolder?

Comment: @mmm @PieterGoosen I replaced `get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID()) === 'mytemplate.php'` with `is_page( 8 )` (8 is the ID of the page) and now the function works. But how to use the template slug?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam The template is located in the child theme main folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `is_page(8)` will make your code a bit static. Let's make it dynamic as you're after with `is_page_template()`:

```
<?php
function prefix_conditional_body_class( $classes ) {
    if( is_page_template('mytemplate.php') )
        $classes[] = 'mytemplate';

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'prefix_conditional_body_class' );
```

Worked for me in a child theme with the template file in the root of the child theme, using template twentyfifteen.

And I don't know why you need another class to be added, if you are using `body_class()` you will already get two classes there: `page-template-mytemplate` and `page-template-mytemplate-php`. They will be unique and you can use them.

Comment: No success :(. Maybe because of my theme? And my page with a custom theme don't have these two classes. BTW, I assign the template to this page with a function (I will update the question). I cannot do that from the admin dashboard, because I don't have this option. Maybe this function is wrong?

Comment: *And my page with a custom theme don't have these two classes.* - :) hahaha

Comment: :) hahaha, but it is so, or I don't understand something. I have only a `page-template-default` class.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam The whole problem arose because of the wrong structure of my template, which I just adapted from the parent theme (missed the name of template: `Template Name: My Template`). Now the problem is solved and I can assign an additional body class with the first code snippet from my question. Your code will also work if you will remove the `return` from the conditional `if`. Now it produces two warnings: `Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /var/www/.../public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 721.
Warning: join(): Invalid arguments ...`

Comment: now that you have change the template, you may have the CSS classes already in the body element